# Separate and print all the words that have three letters

Tags: vb.net

I need some help with a program that will extract from a `RichTextBox` all the words that have three letters and write the sum of these words?

I tried this:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strInput As String
    strInput = RichTextBox1.Text
    Dim strSplit() As String
    strSplit = strInput.Split(CChar(" "))
    MsgBox("Number of words: " & strSplit.Length)
End Sub
```

However this is only counting and I do not know how I can set a condition to count only words that have three letters.

Comment: this not **VBA** its **vb.net**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use LINQ to count the array items with length 3.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim strInput As String


    strInput = RichTextBox1.Text
    Dim strSplit() As String
    strSplit = strInput.Split(CChar(" "))

    Dim count = From x In strSplit Where x.Length = 3
    Dim sum = (From x In count Select x.Length).Sum()

    MsgBox("Number of words: " & count.Count.ToString())
    MsgBox("All the 3 letter words: " & String.Join(" ", count).ToString())
    MsgBox("sum of the 3 letter words: " & sum.ToString())

End Sub
```

Comment: , i am new here. how to do that?

Comment: no problem you need to click the check mark. Read this http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers :)